# Gitlab equivalent for axes/axis of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, cicd

In jenkins it is possible to use `axes` and `axis` parameters in a descriptive script to have various permutations of pipelines/jobs.

Is there any equivalent keyword or method in GITLAB CI/CD ?

Answer (score 3):

the feature is called `matrix builds`, which can be easily achieved via

```
jobs:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - 'test'
        - 'foo'
  script: echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

This will generate two jobs one for `test` and one for `foo` and print out the respectively option. for further details see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs You can also do multiple variables and connections like:

```yaml
  # copied from the official gitlab docs
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROVIDER: aws
        STACK:
          - monitoring
          - app1
          - app2
      - PROVIDER: ovh
        STACK: [monitoring, backup, app]
      - PROVIDER: [gcp, vultr]
        STACK: [data, processing]
```

Sometimes you want to have just a cartesian product of an build, than you can achieve this by

```
parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROVIDER: [aws, ovh, gcp, vultr]
        STACK: [a, b, c, d]
```

GitLab does not offer direct excludes tough, and you have to use `rules:if` to exclude special combinations.

Comment: This is not the same as the matrix in Jenkins. This sample creates 10 jobs (3 × aws + 3 × ovh + 2 × gcp + 2 × vultr). In a Jenkins matrix this combination of values would lead to 36 jobs: 3 × 3 × 2 × 2 (i.e. cartesian product). So, in GitLab it's more an array of vectors not a real matrix.

Comment: well that depends on how you handle the matrix - gitlab just decides to handle excludes differently - we could also put all in one matrix part with 4 providers and multiple stacks, and work with the `rules` to exclude them. I do not see a big difference in the outcome, more in how it is defined. - this second example is more like 3 matrices within one job

Comment: Can you add a pipeline definition (with the values of your second sample above) to your answer that does the same as Jenkins does? I'm really interested in this, too.

Comment: like that or am i missing something?

Comment: This produces 16 jobs (4 + 4 + 4 + 4), doesn' it?

Comment: yeah 4x4 like the cartesian product - or am i still missing something? should i add a third variable to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238621/discussion-between-simon-schrottner-and-gerold-broser).

Comment: If you don't mind I'd like to see a definition with the values of the 3 providers and 3 stacks of your second sample that produces 36 jobs.

Comment: it does not, because it is actually the same as defining 3 separate axes for a the same job - it adds even more flexibility. it offers the same functionality as axes/axis but allows you to define multiple sets of those. So for the answer of the person asking, it is the tool he is looking for, no it is not directly the same feature, because you get another/additional level for configuration. so i am not sure what you are looking for, or trying to proof - or what you want me to add to my answer that it is sufficient for your cause.

Comment: I'm not trying to proof anything. I'd just like to see a definition with the mentioned values that produces this: https://imgur.com/a/8HowXYs, i.e. four dimensions with 3, 3, 2, 2 values in it. If your answer is "Sorry, I don't know." or "Sorry, it's not possible." it's fine for me, too. :)

Comment: so 3x3x2x2 dimension should result in 36 jobs - it creates 46 jobs -  https://gitlab.com/aepfli/cartesian-product/-/pipelines/396888800/builds - also as a reference https://gitlab.com/aepfli/cartesian-product/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Thanks for the links. That's  what I was looking for. Is "46" a typo? Your first link says "_36 jobs for main in 15 seconds (queued for 1 second)_"

Comment: yes it is, sadly i can not edit anymore